# Use Apache 2 + mod_wsgi for Python app

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, python-3.3

I'm trying to use Apache 2 + mod_wsgi for my Python app.
But get an error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@test.local and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My configurations: Ubuntu 12.04, Apache2, Python3.3, Django 1.6, libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3.

My settings.

Folder structure:

```
www
└── test.local
    ├── test_site
    │   ├── manage.py
    │   └── test_site
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── settings.py
    │       ├── urls.py
    │       └── wsgi.py
    └── test_site.wsgi
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.2   test.local
127.0.1.1   ube-home

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.local

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.local
    ServerName test.local
        ServerAlias www.test.local

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ube/www/test.local/test_site.wsgi

    DocumentRoot /home/ube/www/test.local
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ube/www/test.local/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride ALl
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/home/ube/www/test.local/test_site.wsgi

```
import os
import sys  
sys.path.append('/home/ube/www/test.local/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test_site.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I haven't forgotten:

```
sudo a2ensite test.local
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Error log says:

```
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/ube/www/test.local/test_site.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=15638): Target WSGI script '/home/ube/www/test.local/test_site.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=15638): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ube/www/test.local/test_site.wsgi'.
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/ube/www/test.local/test_site.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Sun Mar 30 01:35:06 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

Comment: Where is Django installed? Does the Apache user have read rights to that location?

Comment: Django installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages. The test site is located in the /home/ube/www/test.local. Rights to this a folder: 0775/drwxrwxr-x.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in my case:

```
import os
import sys  
sys.path.append('/home/ube/www/test.local/test_site/')
sys.path.append('/home/ube/www/test.local/')
sys.path.append('/home/ube/www/')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'test_site.settings'

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

I added more sys.path =).